# Cannot catch BadRequestException thrown by FilesInterceptor

Tags: node.js, nestjs, multer

I am trying to set up a logic to save uploaded files using Multer.
To do this, I follow the Nestjs tutorial and use the "FilesInterceptor" interceptor.

**controller file :**

```
import {
    Controller,
    FileValidator,
    ParseFilePipe,
    Post,
    UploadedFiles,
    UseInterceptors
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { FilesInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { Public } from 'src/auth/decorators/public.decorator';
import { MimeTypeValidationPipe } from './pipes/mimetype.validation.pipe';

const ACCEPTED_FILE_MIMETYPES = ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png"]
const validators: FileValidator[] = [
    new MimeTypeValidationPipe({ accepted: ACCEPTED_FILE_MIMETYPES })
];

@Controller('uploads')
export class UploadsController {

    @Public()
    @Post("/")
    @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor("files"))
    public async create(
        @UploadedFiles(new ParseFilePipe({ validators })) 
        files: Express.Multer.File[]
    ){
        files[0].originalname
        const filenames = files.map(({ originalname }) => originalname)
        return { filenames };
    }
}
```

However, when I test the behavior of the server when the number of uploaded files exceeds the limit, the server returns me an error 500 (As if the error was not handled).
I then try to catch it by using an ExcepetionFilter like this one:

```
@Catch()
class TestFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: any, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        console.debug(exception)
        if(exception instanceof HttpException) console.debug("This is an HTTP Exception !");
        else console.debug("This is NOT an HTTP Exception");
        const response = host.switchToHttp().getResponse<Response>();
        return response.status(500).json({statusCode: 500 , message: "ERROR" });
    }
}
```

And i get the following output :

```
BadRequestException: Too many files
    at transformException (~/development/Nest/nestapi/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/multer/multer/multer.utils.js:19:20)
    at ~/development/Nest/nestapi/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/multer/interceptors/files.interceptor.js:18:73
    at ~/development/Nest/nestapi/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:53:37
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:202:9)
    at listener (~/development/Nest/nestapi/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:170:15)
    at onFinish (~/development/Nest/nestapi/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:101:5)
    at callback (~/development/Nest/nestapi/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:55:10)
    at IncomingMessage.onevent (~/development/Nest/nestapi/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:93:5)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12) {
  response: { statusCode: 400, message: 'Too many files', error: 'Bad Request' },
  status: 400
}
This is NOT an HTTP Exception
```

The filter indicates that it is NOT an HTTPException.
However, while digging in the FilesInterceptor.ts code I notice that the caught errors are handled by a small utility function "transformException" which is supposed to transform the Multer error into an HttpException (depending on the error code returned by Multer)

**multer.utils.ts file (from nest repo)**

```
import {
  BadRequestException,
  HttpException,
  PayloadTooLargeException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { multerExceptions } from './multer.constants';

export function transformException(error: Error | undefined) {
  if (!error || error instanceof HttpException) {
    return error;
  }
  switch (error.message) {
    case multerExceptions.LIMIT_FILE_SIZE:
      return new PayloadTooLargeException(error.message);
    case multerExceptions.LIMIT_FILE_COUNT:
    case multerExceptions.LIMIT_FIELD_KEY:
    case multerExceptions.LIMIT_FIELD_VALUE:
    case multerExceptions.LIMIT_FIELD_COUNT:
    case multerExceptions.LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE:
    case multerExceptions.LIMIT_PART_COUNT:
      return new BadRequestException(error.message);
  }
  return error;
}
```

I don't understand why my filter (and NestJS' unhandledExceptionFilter) can't detect this exception, since for me it is supposed to be an instance of HttpException.

Can you help me?

Best regards

Comment: Is this all in the same project, or is part of it in a library or external package or similar?

Comment: It's a all-in-one nestJs project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have 2 copies of @nestjs/common being included in your project.  The code that creates the error is using one copy, and your exception filter is using the other copy.  When your code is checking `instanceof`, it's checking to see if the exception is an instance of `HttpException` from *it's* copy of @nestjs/common, but it's not, it's an instance of `HttpException` from the other copy of @nestjs/common.  This is known as "multiple realms" (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof#instanceof_and_multiple_realms).

The way to fix this is to make sure you only have 1 copy of @nestjs/common in your project.  Often, the reason you have 2 is because you have 2 package.json files with different version specs that they call for (e.g. "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0" in one package.json, and "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0" in another).  You may need to use e.g. the `overrides` key to force a dependency to use the same version that you use elsewhere.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think this is exactly what happened
As i mentionned in my answer, i tried to update multer dependency manually by doing ```npm install``` inside ```node_modules/@nest/platform-express```. This must have messed up adjacent dependencies and like you say, create a copy of another dependency by mistake.
To solve this, i added an ```override``` option in my main ```package.json``` file to override the multer dependency version. After deleting and installing all the dependencies again, everything went back to normal.
Best regards

Comment: @mrflish would you mind clicking the button to accept this as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry!

I think the problem is with me.

The LTS version (1.4.4-lts.1) of multer is buggy. So I decided to downgrade to 1.4.4 (version in which the bug in question does not occur). But to do so, I had to downgrade the nested dependency manually by doing `npm install multer@1.4.4` in the `node_modules/@nest/platform-express` directory.

But that's when nestjs starts to format my errors badly.

The funny thing is that going back (`npm install multer@1.4.4-lts.1` to the `node_modules/@nest/platform-express` directory), it doesn't solve the problem (Errors are still badly handled) and I have to delete the `node_modules/@nest/platform-express` folder and reinstall the package from the root of the project to get everything back in order (But with the LTS version bug, of course).

It's weird.